# Запятая перед повторяющимися союзами

Tags: пунктуация

Так и сидел, и думал.

Нужно ли запятая после сидел. Я думаю, что да, потому что мы имеем дело с повторяющимся союзом "и". Прав ли я?

Answer (score 5):

Согласна с Виктором, что запятая не нужна. Но обоснование, по-моему, другое. Здесь нет двух союзов. Первое И - частица. Сравните: ***Так и*** сидел. А второе соединяет однородные сказуемые. ***Так и*** сидел и думал.

Answer (score 0):

У Розенталя на этот счет есть правило: " При двух однородных членах с повторяющимся союзом "И" запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов), например: Ой, полна, полна коробушка, есть и ситец и парча. Он ею и жил и дышал. В Вашем предложении это смысловое единство как раз налицо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ